# CSS horizontal dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with a CSS dropdown horizontal menu.
Can you help me with this?

HTML:

```
<div id="menucontainer" align="center">
    <div id="menubar" align="center">
        <ul class="mainnav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><a href="business.html">Business</a></li>
                        <li><a href="acca.html">• ACCA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cat.html">• Certified Accounting Technician</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><a href="english.html">English</a></li>
                        <li><a href="generalenglish.html">• General English</a></li>
                        <li><a href="camexenglish.html">• Cambridge Exam English</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="column">
                        <li><a href="computing.html">Computing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
          <li><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="studyarea.html">Study Area</a></li>
                    <li><a href="itlab.html">IT Lab</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="airportpickup.html">Airport Pickup</a></li>
                    <li><a href="firstday.html">First Day Orientation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
<li><a href="international.html">International</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="aboutuk.html">About UK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutlondon.html">About London</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
<li><a href="admissions.html">Admissions</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="entryreq.html">Entry Requirements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="howtoapply.html">How to Apply</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="messagefrom.html">Message from the Principal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="whychoose.html">Why Choose</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
<li><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="byemail.html">By Email</a></li>
                    <li><a href="byphoneorfax.html">By Phone or Fax</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* 2nd container */
#menucontainer { width:100%; height:54px; background-color:#872e26; }

#menubar { width:950px; height:54px; }

#headerx { width:100%; height:5px; background:#872e26; background-image:url(../images/footerx.png); background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat; }
/* 2nd container end */

/* drop menu */
.mainnav { list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0; text-align:center; }

.mainnav li { float:left; width:118.75px; }

.mainnav a { text-decoration:none; color:#fff; display:block; line-height:54px; }

.mainnav a:hover { background-color:#e3c153; color:#872e26; }

.submenu { display:none; list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0; background-color:#872e26; position:absolute; float:none; font-size:10px; }

li:hover .submenu { display:block; }

.column { list-style-type:none; text-align:center; }
/* drop menu end*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8Rc9/11/

1. I would like that the elements from the dropdown to be one on top of the other, NOT like they are now, one next to the other.
2. Also, the submenu inherits the size from the navigation. Can I define less line-height for submenu only?

Tried everything and I do not seem to find the fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the parent `li` elements:

```
.mainnav li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 118.75px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then add `position:absolute` to the child `.submenu` element. This absolutely positions the elements relative to the parent element.

```
li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you want to change the `line-height` of the child `li` elements, you could use the direct sibling combinator, `>` to target the direct children of the descendant `li` elements:

```
.column > li a {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/asPvR/)

Comment: One more thing please, if you look under **Courses**, how can I create 3 columns, like float:left, out of **Business, English and Computing**. So each of these three to be on separate column, so they will not extend too much to get out of screen? Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel You would have to modify the HTML structure. Which `li` do you want them to extend out of?

Comment: So I would like to arrange the submenu under COURSES to be arranged in 3 columns, Business,English and Computing. Of course each having it's own "li"s. Hope you understand me.