# How to make a dropdown menu appear on top of another div

Tags: html, css

I have added a dropdown menu to my current menu.

But the problem is that the dropdown part stays behind the content.

How do I resolve this, rather than making the position absolute and fixed manual measures?

Thanks

Comment: did you give the higher `z-index` value to drop down menu?

Comment: show us some code you could be miss using float property or position or many things

Comment: the z-index:1/2; works

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `z-index` of the `dropdown` menu to a higher value

For example:

```
#menu {
    z-index: 1;
}

#dopdown {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

UPDATE:

You might wanna set the `z-index` of the other elements in the menu to `1` too.

Comment: are you sure only giving `z-index` value this will work?check it first.

Answer (score 0):

try to set z-index of your dropdown container more than that of content.

```
<div style="z-index:1;">
 Content div
</div>
<div style="z-index:2">
your dropdown content 
</div>
```

just set your css and html as you need , whatever your question is , will be solved with z-index property.

Comment: this will be accepted as answer only if you provide them a working Demo.. otherwise use comment secion.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following links :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21394831/1127263

http://css3menu.com/

http://www.cssterm.com/css-menus/horizontal-css-menu/simple-drop-down-menu

http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/css-horizontal-menu-with-dropdowns/#

Comment: Could you please state the reason for the downvote so I can improve my answers in the future?